# asp.net entity framework - Complicated Queries with join + Membership user

Tags: asp.net, sql, entity-framework

I have 2 tables.
Users - have userID, userMainGroup and userMinorGroup
Tasks - TaskId, UserId

My goal is:
 I have current CurrentuserId and i want to show him all the tasks that were created by users from the same MainGroup as he.

In SQL i would write:

```
Select *
From Tasks Left join Users on tasks.Id=users.id
Where users.MainGroup=CurrentuserMainGroup; (var)
```

How do i do it using entity framework?

I understood that to make a join i need to write something like:

```
var tasks = from t in db.tasks
            from u in db.users
            where t.Id=u.Id
            select new {t.Id, t.name....}
```

but where do i put the condition Where on the MainGroup?

Comment: Why are you "left joining" the Users table when you are applying a filter over it?

Comment: because i need to know userMainGroup only for users that have a task. The reason for join is to join the "Task" with mainGroup that the user that created this task - belong to.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
var data= (from con in db.tasks
          let UserMainGroup = db.users.where(x=>x.id==con.id).FirstOrDefault()
          where  UserMainGroup.MainGroup=CurrentuserMainGroup
          select new {
          ID=con.id,
          Name=con.name
          }).ToList();
```

i think this will help you.......

Comment: Thanks. If i want that the data will gave all the columns, do we have something like * in SQL? or i need to write ALL the columns name in SELECT new?

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended that you use navigation properties in stead of manually coded joins:

```
from t in db.Tasks
where t.User.MainGroup == currentuserMainGroup
select new {t.Id, t.name.... , t.User.Name, ... }
```

Comment: Only if these tables have been created in the mdx with the relationship between them, otherwise, I would suggest the use of the join keyword.

Comment: Sure, there may be reasons not to have associations, but it is recommended.